# Cocos2D from monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is the Cocos2D binding presented here : https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/cocos2d usable?

Someone familiar with the Cocos2D api should be able to see if https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/cocos2d/cocos2d.cs contains all the functions that they have used when going the objective-c way.

I am unfamiliar with the Cocos2D api so I need someone who is familiar to just have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last commit: 8 months ago. The commit history shows there was only [this one commit](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/commits/master/cocos2d), and it was named "work-in-progress". Interestingly, the history even says the commit was 11 months ago. No idea where the discrepancy is coming from.

So it's certainly not up to date, and likely to be incomplete. The single commit also tells me that it's not actively maintained and not used by others (who might report bugs, supply code fixes and improvements) either.

Personally I wouldn't put my trust in this. It's not a matter of it being usable or not.

You can always make some quick tests to see if the cocos2d implementation is actually working, and not inherently broken. That shouldn't take more than an hour or two to find out whether you feel confident enough about cocos2d+monotouch.

Comment: Since I posted I have gone on to read how to use btouch and learnt basic syntax of objective-c (all thats needed is to understand class declarations and function signatures) and feel confident that I can use it and modify it in case of any hiccups :) Thanks.